# Multiple template functions inside non-template class

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class `foo` which contain two template functions `Add()` and `Subtract()`.

```
struct foo
{
    template <typename U>
    U* Add();
    template <typename U>
    U* Subtract();
};
```

Is it correct to use same template parameter `U` for both of them? Also do I need to write `template <typename U>` every time before a template function declaration?

Comment: Did the code compile? Why do you think member function templates would be different to non-member function templates with respect to how they are declared?

Comment: @DietmarKühl the fact that code compiled is not sufficient proof that the code is a. correct b. working as intended.

Comment: @SergeyA: true. However, using for example two entirely different compilers and seeing if they both swallow the code is fair indication of things being OK. Also, it remains: why would things be different compared to non-member function templates?

Comment: @DietmarKühl well, OP had a question. May be they would expect that there is a way to generally define next X functions as templates with the same parameters? Not inconceivable.

Comment: @DietmarKühl I often found that people new to a language and often new to programming itself tend to question things we take for granted or things that we consider easily deductible by means of logic. This is caused by a big void in knowledge of the subject that makes you question yourself if maybe there is something there in the big unknown you have that might contradict something you found/believe/deduced.

Comment: For instance, when I was first introduced to USB at a friend's computer I asked "In which of the two USB connection should I plug the mouse?" . That got a laugh from my friends (and me later), but from my perspective that was a perfectly valid concern. I knew absolutly nothing about USB and even though both connections looked the same at first glance there could have been some unknown aspect/reason that differentiated between the two.

Comment: @bolov and your question could be valid and very important (depending on when this actually has happened)! I have a laptop where two ports are USB3 and two are USB2. Probably makes no difference for mouse, but makes a lot of difference for USB sticks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can use the same name for template parameters in different functions, the same way you can name arguments the same. Those names in different functions are completely unrelated.

And yes, you have to use keyword `template` as per C++ grammar.